# Getting folder contents on remote system is slow in Powershell

Tags: file, powershell, directory

When I am trying to get a folder contents for remote system the command always takes a real long time before the next command can be executed if the folder contains hundreds of files.  Is there something wrong with my code and is there maybe something more efficient that wouldn't cause to get hung up?

Here's my code:

```
$targetFolder = "\\someServer\d$\someFolder"
write-host $targetFolder
$Files = Get-ChildItem $targetFolder | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)}
```

If I run the same command on a local system the code executes without a hiccup.

Comment: Have You tried using invoke-command to execute the call to get-childitem on the remote system?

Comment: The remote system is an older system without Powershell on the system, so I didn't think I could use the Invoke-Command on it.

Comment: then i think you are stuck with your current code, installing powershell on the other system is not an option i guess? Assuming that $targetFolder is a smb share you could try to mount it as psdrive and see if get-childitem performs faster on this, i doubt it though

Answer (score 0):

Sadly because my remote system doesn't have Powershell and it doesn't look like I would be able to put Powershell on it, I resorted to using the COM object of the FileSystemObject which seems to be much faster the GCI.  here's the code I'm using instead:

```
$fso = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject
$targetFolder = "\\someServer\d$\someFolder"
write-host $targetFolder
$folder = $fso.GetFolder($targetFolder)
$files = $folder.Files
foreach($file in $files){
if ($file.DateLastModified -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)){write-host $file.path}
}
```